# What security can be added to Java Applets?

Tags: java, security, applet, obfuscation

When building a Java Applet are there any steps that can be made to prevent a user invoking internal methods?

Theoretically most objects can be analysed and methods can be invoked on a client machine.

In addition to obfuscation are there any other steps that can help prevent this?

My situation is to secure a game where the top score is sent direct from the client.

Comment: Do you mean stop people grabbing your jar and writing something that uses it?

Comment: No, the concern for this question is to stop high scores being faked and sent to the server.

Comment: At first this seems hopeless, but on second thought I bet there are some clever things you can do. +1 for this question because I would love to see some brainpower applied here.

Comment: This question reminds me of the Greatest Hacker Story Ever Told: http://slashdot.org/articles/01/01/25/1343218.shtml

Comment: Are you wanting something like the Sony rootkit?

Comment: No, I'm not trying to interfere with (or install anything on) the user's computer (if this is what you mean). I just wish to make the game more difficult to be tampered with. Obfuscation is one step, and I was wondering if there is any other step that I could take. I understand that 100% reliability on a user machine is unobtainable but I wish to make it uneconomical.

Answer (score 3):

If your game is too difficult to be automated and played by a bot in a much fruitful manner than any human could do, then it would be a good idea to request the game's state from the server at certain random intervals. You could implement a [CAPTCHA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA)-like mechanism that would blend into the game's story and bring the level of [Challenge-Response authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Challenge-response_authentication) to a small Turing-like test, where the player would have to "prove" from time to time that he is human by solving a specific puzzle. All this time, you verify the evolution of the score, and reject any values that would not fit a precomputed formula of maximal score per level or per unit of time, given the current system's state. I am not a security expert, but I imagine that all this would give a potential attacker quite a hard time.

Comment: Thanks and plus one for a thoughtful answer.